# Datagrid gives null values using for loop in WPF

Tags: excel, wpf, datagrid

I have a dataGrid with more than 100 rows in it. I am extracting it to an existing Excel file. I can open the file and add values to the sheet. My problem is, the value becomes null as soon as it gets to the 14th row.

I tried reversing the order of the data in the datagrid just to be sure that it's not the value or data in the dataGrid that is causing the issue but I still get the same result. Only the first 13 rows are extracted to the Excel sheet. The for loop still goes to the rest of the loop but it seems to not get the values.

Here is my code:

```
var path = @"D:\Reports\Sample.xlsx";
            var excel = new Excel.Application {Visible = true};
            var wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
            var ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets["summary"];
for (var i = 0; i < Grid.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Grid.Items.Count; j++)
    {
        var b = Grid.Columns[i].GetCellContent(Grid.Items[j]) as TextBlock; =====> ON THE 14th ROW, the "b" variable becomes null all throught out the for-loop
        var myRange = (Range)ws.Cells[j + 2, i + 1];
        try
        {
            if (b != null) myRange.Value2 = b.Text;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
       Thread.Sleep(100); 
    }
}
```

This is the Excel file created. Values are not extracted any more after the 14th row.

[image]

Comment: This may be caused by virtualization. You should not iterate over the cell content, but the source data instead. Also note that you must not call Thread.Sleep in the UI thread. It is blocked and your UI becomes unresponsive.

Comment: Oh I don't i tend to..I just place the delay for debugging reaaons. Thank you for that tip though. I got it working by doing your suggestion.